Is there a way to parameterize a type with a value of another one in Haskell?
I have a type A and an associated type that represents a pair of A, specifically (A, A). I also have a smart constructor for this pair type, which takes a set of A and two values of A. The constructor performs some checks (e.g., ensuring the values belong to the set) and returns the pair of the second and third arguments if the checks pass.
I want to keep track of the set used to create a value of the pair type, but I would like to avoid storing the set in each instance of the pair type. I was considering parameterizing the pair type by the type corresponding to the set of A. Is this feasible in Haskell?
Clarification:
Let’s say there are two lists of integers, [1, 2, 3] and [1, 2, 4]. I have a smart constructor that takes a list of integers, and two integers.
The constructor returns a pair of integers. For example using the first list [1, 2, 3] with 1 and 2, and the second list [1, 2, 4] with 1 and 2, both successfully return the pair (1, 2).
However, in this current setup, the resulting pairs lose the context of which list was used to create them.
Goal:
I want to adjust the types such that the resulting pair is distinguishable based on the list that was used to create it, but I don't want to store the list within each value of the adjusted second type.
Update: Possible solution: DataKinds extension seems to do what I need.

It sounds like what you're hoping for is dependent types, which lets you have values as type components.  (Haskell has bits and pieces of that feature, but probably not enough to do what you want.)  But it really depends on what you mean by "the type corresponding to the set of A."

I think it might clean up a bit if you provide an example. It probably also helps to explain what you try to achieve, not that much how you try to achieve that.

I'm leaning towards "no, it's not possible, at least not conveniently". Still, the first question I'd ask myself is: "is the set known at compile time?". If so, there might be a way to represent it in the type. Otherwise, you'll need to store it at runtime in some way (whether it also appears inside types or not). Anyway, a few keywords you might want to research: depend types (not supported in Haskell), singletons, GADTs (limited version of dependent types), type families. These are non-trivial to learn and use, though, so YMMV.

@chi, I wanted to use the module I’m developing as a library for the user. If the user wanted to combine in some way “pairs” created via the smart constructor using different “sets,” I would not allow it to happen. But to store the set within each “pair” doesn't sound great either. What if the user had many “pairs?”

Keep in mind that let set = veryLargeDataStructure in [(1,set), (2,set), (3,set)] will only store the large set data structure once, not three times. Those pairs roughly contain an integer and a pointer to the same set. It's not ideal to have an extra pointer in each pair, but perhaps it's good enough for some purposes.

@chi, I found the DataKinds extension, which seems to do what I need. I should check it out first though to be sure

Check out Ghosts of Departed Proofs, it's about doing exactly this kind of thing using a generalization of the phantom existential type trick used by ST.
